# How to provide list of OData entities and its URL's to end users without using Service Document URL in Olingo OData

Tags: odata

Do we need to develop any specific web page to provide all entities details along with entities details including URL.

Not got enough info on this topic. Most of search provided suggesting Service Document, but I don't want to use.